# How can i play different video files in android application?

Tags: android

i am developing an android application. In my application i need to play different format video files which are coming from server. My application getting the video links from server. Those are different formats like avi,flv,mkv,mp4. I tried to played .3gp file link successfully but the remaining formats are not supported. May be android supports only .3gp.
I tried a way to play the video links in web view and got failed. Please suggest me is there any way to play the avi,flv,mkv,mp4 file formats.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good point to start is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Android should support the following codecs: H.263, H.264 AVC, MPEG-4 SP, VP8.

Maybe the videos are not correctly encoded or have just another container format?
Are you trying to stream the videos?

You also should have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Vitamio http://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/

Or from this: https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle